# If function has positve integral on domain then there exist interval and positve number such that function is bounded below by that number on Interval

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

> Suppose $\int_a^b f$ exist and positive Prove that there exist interval [c,d]  and m>0 such that $f(x)\geq m$.

I was thinking to prove by contradiction . Suppose there is no interval with above property

If we have partition then in any partion our function take negative value.

I donot know how to argue then

Please can anyone suggest me how to prove?

Comment: What are the assumptions on $f$ ?

Comment: Only assumption is that f is integrable and its integral over [a,b] is positive

Comment: The statement is obviously false for the Lebesgue integral, so I guess you must be using the Riemann integral.

Comment: Yes Sir I was asking about Reimann Integral I do not know about Lebegue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Riemann integral $\int_a^b f(x)\; dx  > 0$, there is a partition $P: a = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n = b$ so that the lower Darboux sum
$\sum_{i=1}^n \inf_{t \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} f(t) (x_i - x_{i-1}) > 0$.
For this to be positive, at least one of the summands must be positive, and thus we have an interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ such that $\inf_{t \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} f(t) > 0$.  Take
$m = \inf_{t \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} f(t)$.